# Ring Homomorphism from $R\to R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

I need to list all Ring Homomorphisms from $R\to R$ where $R$ is a $PID$.

Let $\phi:R\to R$ be a ring homomorphism. We know submodules of free modules are free. $R$ itself is a free module. Thus, every ideal of $R$ is free module of rank $0$ or $1$. We know kernel of a ring homomorphism is an ideal thus ker $\phi \equiv R$ or $\{1\}$. First case is not possible since $\phi(1)\ne1$.
Thus there is only a single Ring Homomorphism from $R$ to $R$ namely identity

Is the proof correct? if yes, how can I extend it to $\phi:R^n\to R$?
Actually I have seen it written that $Hom_R(M,R)\cong R^n$ where $M$ is free module of rank $n$ but I think it should be $R^{n-1}$

Comment: Hint: The complex numbers form a PID, and there is a non-trivial automorphism $\mathbb{C} \to\mathbb{C}.$ This map is however not $\mathbb{C}$-linear.

Comment: The proof is wrong because given an $R$-module $M$ and an $R$-submodule $N$, both free of same finite rank, it does not follow that $M=N$. For example $\mathbb{Z} \supset 2\mathbb{Z}$. The conclusion is also wrong; take for example the ring homomorphism $k[x] \to k[x]$ that sends $x$ to $x^2$.